# What is the behavior when a new C programming language standard is official, the old standard is ALWAYS compatible?

Tags: c

Are there any deprecation between `c89/90` `c99` `c11` `c18`? Or only recommendation of avoid certain function like `strlen` and use a "safer" `strnlen_s`?

Comment: Yes; the `gets` function is the biggest example

Comment: ...which is mentioned in the [Wikipedia article for C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Changes_from_C99).

Comment: `gets` is not only depracated in C11, but in fact completely removed. The changes can be found in the appendixes of each standard document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compatibility of C89/C90, C99 and C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535927/compatibility-of-c89-c90-c99-and-c11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer standards are not guaranteed to be compatible, even though the committee has a (far too) strong focus on backwards compatibility.

- C90 is not completely compatible with newer versions.
- C11 and C17 are compatible with C99, apart from some corrections.

Official recommendations of functions to avoid are found in:

- C17 6.11 *Future language directions*, and
- C17 6.32 *Future library directions*

Notably, the official recommendations are free from misguided Microsoft propaganda regarding the string handling functions etc.

Unofficial recommendations by yours sincerely here: 
[Which functions from the standard library must (should) be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518).

Answer (score 1):

The following code is valid in C89, deprecated under C99, and invalid in C11 and further, due to its use of the unsafe function `gets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    puts("What's your name?");
    gets(str);
    printf("Hello %s!\n", str);
}
```