# Does Linux kernel list implementation cause UB?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, linux-kernel

Prerequisites:

1. As per [C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838855/is-storing-an-invalid-pointer-automatically-undefined-behavior), pointer arithmetics that would yield an invalid pointer, cause undefined behavior.
2. Linux source code [seems to conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600497/which-c-version-is-used-in-the-linux-kernel) with C standard in a desire to be compatible with most architectures.
3. [Linux's list implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/09162bc32c880a791c6c0668ce0745cf7958f576/include/linux/list.h#L618) contains the following code(formatting preserved, probably the idea for another question is how to set proper tabulation width using Stackoverflow syntax):

```c
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)

#define list_next_entry(pos, member) \
    list_entry((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member)

#define list_first_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    list_entry((ptr)->next, type, member)

#define list_entry_is_head(pos, head, member)               \
    (&pos->member == (head))

#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member);    \
         !list_entry_is_head(pos, head, member);            \
         pos = list_next_entry(pos, member))
```

4. Typical usecase of the aforementioned list implementation is having structure of say type `struct A`, containing a head for the list of stuctures of type `struct B`.

**Q**: Let's assume `offsetof(struct B, entry_in_list) > offsetof(struct A, list_head)` and the following loop is implemented:

```
struct A* A_ptr = something_meaningful;
struct B* pos = NULL;
list_for_each_entry(pos, &A_ptr->list_head, entry_in_list) {
  do_something();
}
```

Then last (before loop exit) evaluation of `list_next_entry(pos, member)` would extend to:

```c
container_of(A_ptr->list_head, struct B, entry_in_list) = 
 = (char*)A_ptr->list_head - offsetof(struct B, entry_in_list) =
 = (char*)A_ptr + offsetof(struct A, list_head) - offsetof(struct B, entry_in_list)
```

, which, according to our assumption, would point to area before A struct. Assuming this area  does not contain allocated memory, the result of the `container_of()` macro would be an invalid pointer, thus causing UB(in general case OFC) in Linux. Is this reasoning plausible or am I mistaken somehow?

Or are there some parts of the standard universally considered to not be worth to follow?

Comment: The Linux kernel uses some GCC extensions such as `typeof` and also makes some assumptions about the C implementation.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for the comment. But it seems necessary to not only make assumptions about the compiler(and therefore C implementation), but also about architectures on which this generic interface will be used. I believe that GCC may just translate this C code to assembly assuming that it does not violate C standard, and UB will only be disclosed when CPU sees invalid pointer assigned to a register associated with ```pos```.

Comment: You are correct that the `list_for_each_entry` and `list_entry_is_head` macros are playing fast and loose with the C standard. The `pos` variable is not pointing to a `struct B` object when the loop terminating condition is expected to be false, so accessing `&pos->entry_in_list` in `list_entry_is_head` invokes UB there.

Comment: @IanAbbott I believe this counts as a full-fledged answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected by OP, the implementation of the `list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)` macro depends on *undefined behavior* in the C language in order for the loop termination condition `!list_entry_is_head(pos, head, member)` to become false.

Assuming the list is non-empty, then after the final iteration, the third "advancing" expression of the `for` loop produces a pointer to an invalid `typeof(*pos)` at an address `offsetof(typeof(*pos), member)` bytes before the `struct list_head` pointed to by `head`. It relies on `&pos->member` nevertheless comparing equal to `head`.

Although it depends on undefined behavior, it is hard for the compiler to determine that `pos` is technically an invalid pointer.  As long as both `pos` and `head` point within the same flat address space, the Linux kernel manages to get away with this bending of the rules.

The alternative would be for `#include <linux/list.h>` to not provide the `list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)` macro at all, and for code to use the `list_for_each(pos, head)` and `list_entry(ptr, type, member)` macros instead (where `pos` is a `struct list_head *` and `ptr` is a `type *`), but that would typically require extra variables in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Additional assertions made when compiling the kernel. These are actually used all over the place.

1. A pointer may be loaded with an address that isn't allocated. You see this on every system call entry. Special care must be taken handling such pointers as dereferencing them can do worse than crash.
2. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is not guaranteed to crash; and the compiler is not allowed to assume that a path that dereferences NULL is unreachable. (This one was added late after a NULL pointer optimization removed a security check.) On some architectures there's actually something there; on other architectures it's just another usermode pointer.

The compiler is told these are true by compiler options. (In fact the first one is generally assumed to be true in flat model, which the kernel is.)

The flag passed to `gcc` is `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`. Reference for null pointer optimization change: https://lwn.net/Articles/342420/

Comment: Thank you, very interesting! I would be grateful if you provided some references/links to LKML/GCC mailing lists discussing introduction of the aforementioned options. Also mentioning the exact options would be nice.

Comment: @Phikimon: Source. You won't find one for flat though. It's still there because the kernel has never been attempted to be ported to an architecture where it didn't use flat memory model.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that this is undefined behavior. According to Richard Biener, [this kind of undefined behavior is not supported/made defined by `-fno-strict-aliasing`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103964#c3). (Clang treats this as undefined as well.)

This particular miscompilation was observed with [Open vSwitch](https://www.openvswitch.org/), but its list macros are clearly modeled after/copied from the kernel. Why does the kernel get away with it?

- It is built with `-fno-strict-aliasing` (although this does not help with this particular case).
- The kernel is less often built with LTO.
- The kernel does not use list heads on the stack.
- Compilers do not recognize the kernel allocation functions.

As a result, compilers do not observe the invalid/impossible object references and do not optimize based on that.

Comment: > The kernel does not use list heads on the stack. <
Why is this relevant?

Comment: It's a variant of a known allocation function: the compiler can observe that there is no valid surrounding object.