# missing braces around initializer in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to write below driver for a use case in my kernel driver. For simplicity I have hardcoded few values here and reduced my array for 1 element, the driver code is as below,

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define MODULE_NAME             ("test-module")
#define BOARD_VER               3
#define BOARD_SAM               2
struct foo {
    int variant;
    char *str[3];
};

struct bar {
    int sample;
    struct foo fooarr[3];
};



static int __init dtcprop_init(void)
{
    unsigned int board_sample, board_variant;
    int i = 0;

    board_sample = BOARD_SAM;
    board_variant= BOARD_VER;

    struct bar bar_array[6] = { 
                    -1, 
                    { 0, NULL,NULL,NULL },
                  };

    if (bar_array[board_sample].sample != -1 && bar_array[board_sample].fooarr[board_variant].variant != -1) {
        while (bar_array[board_sample].fooarr[board_variant].str[i] != NULL) {
            pr_info("%s: %s\n", MODULE_NAME, bar_array[board_sample].fooarr[board_variant].str[i++]);
        }
    } else {
        pr_info("%s: unsupported board\n", MODULE_NAME);
    }

    return 0;
}
arch_initcall(dtcprop_init);
```

But I am getting these warnings which are treated as errors,

```
41:35: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
41:9: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   41 |         struct bar bar_array[6] = {
      |         ^~~~~~
```

I tried several closing braces but this warning does not go away.

1. Is it legal to write an struct array in kernel module,
2. How to correct above driver?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Is there a special reason that you use a comment to provide a code-only answer? Apart from it being a code-only answer I mean. I mean I thank you for not posting code-only answers as answering posts. But posting them instead as comments makes things worse, not better; because we now have an unanswered question which is  less likely to get an actual answer.

Comment: C90 doesn't allow declarations in the middle of the function body, which is why you get the warning. Any particular reason why you are using "stone age mode" on the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

C90 does not allow declarations anywhere except at the top of the surrounding function body, directly after the `{`. So the fix in C90 would be this:

```c
static int __init dtcprop_init(void)
{
    unsigned int board_sample, board_variant;
    int i = 0;
    struct bar bar_array[6] = { 
                    -1, 
                    { 0, NULL,NULL,NULL },
                  };

    board_sample = BOARD_SAM;
    board_variant= BOARD_VER;
```

However, it is better to address the root of the problem, namely that you are using a 34 year old compiler. That's about as wise as running Linux on a 34 year old computer :) Therefore, get rid of any option `-std=gnu89`/`-std=c89`/`-std=gnu90`/`-std=c90`/`-ansi`. None of these should be used. Also update to gcc version 5.0.0 or later, which does not default to C90.

Comment: buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version
arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2023.08-756-g3f23277c41-dirty) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc

Comment: I have followed braces as suggested, also made this struct global. Now its compiling without warning.

Comment: @mrigendra So check your compiler options/make file. Somewhere in there sits an incorrect setting.

Comment: @Lundin: The question is about **Linux kernel** code, which deliberately used `-std=gnu89` until recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600497/which-c-version-is-used-in-the-linux-kernel. So, the suggestion to get rid of `-std` option doesn't look wise.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So what? GNU99 is for the most part 100% backwards-compatible, as long as you don't use C99 features. The main difference would be that you get compiler diagnostics when calling functions that weren't properly declared, which was the biggest flaw in C90. There is nothing in C99 that will break old C89 code except maybe swapping undefined behavior "struct hack" for C99 flexible array members (in which case the original code has a bug).

Comment: @Tsyvarev What doesn't look "wise" is that Linux is apparently falling catastrophically behind. In comparison, the _very_ conservative automotive industry left C89 some >10 years ago even for safety-related applications. Sounds like it is time for a Linux generation change - maybe it is time to hack together a C version of Linux? GNU C's not C.

Comment: GCC v5.1 is a minimum requirement for Linux kernel nowadays (IIRC, i.e. C11 with all features like `_Generic()` should be supported).